# Access a repo's social icon

Tags: github

In the repository settings, Github lets you define an icon/image as "Social preview". Is there a url at which you can access that image programmatically? Something like `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<username>/<repo_name>/icon` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the Social preview of a github project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60381683/how-to-get-the-social-preview-of-a-github-project)

Comment: Not really.. this just says that it's impossible, which I'm having a hard time accepting. I'm also not trying to retrieve it through the API